# Search between dates with exclusion

Tags: sql, mysql, date

I have completed Part 1:
I have a table called Clients and a column in it called Last_Seen. I need to go back 6 Months and forward one week (Search between 180 and 173 days back) and grab those records that were seen during that 7-day window.

I need help with Part 2:

I do NOT want the same client to appear in this 7-day window search IF they were 'Last_Seen' OR have a scheduled appointment in column called 'Scheduled' AFTER that 7 day window. Any idea how to accomplish this?
Thanks!!

I accomplished Part 1 with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Clients
WHERE Last_Seen BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 180 DAY
                    AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY
AND Last_Seen IS NOT NULL
```

ANSWERED MY OWN QUESTION WITH BELOW:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Clients
WHERE Last_Seen BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 180 DAY
                    AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY
AND Last_Seen IS NOT NULL
AND Last_Seen NOT BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY
                      AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND Scheduled NOT BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY
                      AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND Last_Seen NOT BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 172 DAY
                      AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND Scheduled NOT BETWEEN NOW()
                      AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 365 DAY)
```

Comment: Presuming that `Scheduled` is also a date column, then you could just add `AND (Scheduled IS NULL OR Scheduled <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY)`

Comment: Yup. You was probably typing that answer as I was testing the same exact thing, haha. I'll give you the credit though since it is the right answer.

Comment: 180 days is not 6 months, and 180 to 173 is not a 7 day window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The short answer

Assuming `Clients` table looks something like this and current date `2023-10-26`:

| Id | Name | Last_Seen | Scheduled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Client 1 | 2023-09-01 11:00 | NULL |
| 2 | Client 2 | 2023-04-27 10:00 | NULL |
| 3 | Client 3 | 2023-05-02 09:00 | 2023-10-27 14:00 |

We are not interested in `Client 1` as `Last_Seen` does not meet the *"Part 1"* criteria.
Both `Client 2` and `Client 3` meet the *"Part 1"* criteria, but only `Client 2` meets the *"Part 2"* criteria.

The query to achieve this result is simply:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Clients
WHERE Last_Seen >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
  AND Last_Seen <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
AND (
    Scheduled IS NULL OR
    Scheduled < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
);
```

This still seems a little strange as, if a client was `Last_Seen` six months ago but had a `Scheduled` appointment a couple of weeks/months later, surely the `Last_Seen` date should be the date of the `Scheduled` appointment, unless they missed their scheduled appointment, in which case we would want to schedule another?

### The explanation

Your attempt at answering your own question seems a little *wonky*.

Let's start with issues in your solution to *"Part 1"*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Clients
WHERE Last_Seen BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 180 DAY
                    AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY
AND Last_Seen IS NOT NULL;
```

Firstly, `AND Last_Seen IS NOT NULL` is redundant, as it is not possible to satisfy the first criterion (date range) while being null.

Secondly, as pointed out by [ysth in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77362678/search-between-dates-with-exclusion/77363367?noredirect=1#comment136387568_77362678):

> 180 days is not 6 months, and 180 to 173 is not a 7 day window

Your date range criterion evaluates to (if `Last_Seen` is date):

```sql
WHERE Last_Seen BETWEEN '2023-04-29'
                    AND '2023-05-06';
```

which, if your `Last_Seen` column contains dates (not datetimes), is 8 days (`2023-04-29 - 2023-05-06` inclusive). If your `Last_Seen` column contains datetime values it is not so bad as it evaluates to:

```sql
WHERE Last_Seen BETWEEN '2023-04-29 00:00:00'
                    AND '2023-05-06 00:00:00';
```

This is 7 days and 1 second, which probably does not matter, but to be strictly correct should probably be rewritten as:

```sql
WHERE Last_Seen >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
  AND Last_Seen <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH + INTERVAL 1 WEEK;
```

which evaluates to (if `Last_Seen` is datetime):

```sql
WHERE Last_Seen >= '2023-04-26 00:00:00'
  AND Last_Seen <  '2023-05-03 00:00:00';
```

Now onto the issues in your solution to *"Part 2"*, starting with the `Last_Seen` criteria:

```sql
WHERE Last_Seen BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 180 DAY
                    AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY
AND Last_Seen IS NOT NULL
AND Last_Seen NOT BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY
                      AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND Last_Seen NOT BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 172 DAY
                      AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Here is the same set of criteria with the expressions evaluated (assuming `Last_Seen` is datetime):

```sql
WHERE Last_Seen BETWEEN '2023-04-29 00:00:00'
                    AND '2023-05-06 00:00:00'
AND Last_Seen IS NOT NULL
AND Last_Seen NOT BETWEEN '2023-05-06 00:00:00'
                      AND '2023-10-25 00:00:00'
AND Last_Seen NOT BETWEEN '2023-05-07 00:00:00'
                      AND '2023-10-25 00:00:00'
```

Line 3 is redundant as discussed above. Lines 4 & 5 are redundant as it is not possible to satisfy lines 1 & 2, but not 4 & 5 (apart from the unintentional 1 second overlap). Lines 6 & 7 are redundant for the same reason as lines 4 & 5.

And finally, onto the `Scheduled` criteria:

```sql
AND Scheduled NOT BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY
                      AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND Scheduled NOT BETWEEN NOW()
                      AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 365 DAY)
```

evaluates to:

```sql
AND Scheduled NOT BETWEEN '2023-05-06 00:00:00'
                      AND '2023-10-25 00:00:00'
AND Scheduled NOT BETWEEN '2023-10-26 09:24:30'
                      AND '2024-10-25 09:24:30'
```

These criteria do not make a lot of sense. There is a strange hole between `2023-10-25 00:00:00` and `2023-10-26 09:24:30`. Essentially, it seems you are trying to say `Scheduled` is not at or after `2023-05-06 00:00:00`. Because we need to handle null values, this is typically expressed as:

```sql
AND (
    Scheduled IS NULL OR
    Scheduled < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
)
```

Assuming that someone attending an appointment results in `Last_Seen` being updated to the datetime of the `Scheduled` appointment, this could be rewritten as:

```sql
AND (
    Scheduled IS NULL OR
    Scheduled <= Last_Seen
)
```

or possibly:

```sql
AND (
    Scheduled IS NULL OR
    NOT Scheduled > NOW()
)
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hwN7GPCl).

Comment: "Wonky", LOL and it's a fair assessment! I "think" I see what you did. Mine is like getting directions using a GPS which takes 14 turns, 5 side streets, through a lake and across a dam... where yours is turn right at the next light, go 5 miles and it's on the right, haha.  That said, can you explain how `AND (Scheduled IS NULL OR Scheduled <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY);` does the same thing my "wonky" way does regarding "future" scheduled meetings? I REALLY appreciate your help!

Comment: I like _"wonky"_ as it conveys that something is wrong in a light-hearted way ;-) I have added an explanation. I hope this helps. **Note**: it is _probably_ more appropriate to store appointments in a separate table, so you have a record of all appointments made and whether people attended.

Comment: Wow. Thank you SO MUCH! I did not expect that much information to be honest. I think I learned more in the few minutes of reading your explanations than I have in months of beating my head against the proverbial wall! Thanks again. Marked your answer as Accepted.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you.